# Laptop random hibernation

Tags: laptop-repair

Background:
So, I have an Asus k53e notebook, and a week or so ago, it started going into hibernation at random intervals.  I checked the system log, and it said the reason was "button or lid", which I assume meant it registered that I had pressed the power button or closed the lid of the laptop.  When I press the power button, it goes into hibernate and the power light starts blinking, which did not happen with the random hibernations, or with the closing of the lid.  Therefore, I assume that it is registering the lid as being closed.  After doing some research, I found that notebooks register as being open or closed using a magnet on the frame of the lid and a Reed switch on the edge of the bottom case.  (A Reed switch closes in the presence of a magnet).  My conclusion has been that the reed switch must be broken.  As such, I'd like to disassemble my notebook's case and remove the reed switch.  The disassembly instructions are here:
http://gentechpcforums.com/Images/Manuals/K53%20Series%20Guide%20Chapter%2002-v1.0.pdf

The plan is to open the bottom case of the computer and remove the switch with a pair of wire cutters.  Since the switch is off when the notebook is open, the removal of the switch should make the computer register that the lid is always open.

So, my questions are:
1:  Is it possible that something else is causing this, and I should try a simpler solution before opening up my computer?
2:  As someone who has never done a computer repair before, should I get a professional to do it instead?
3:  If I do perform the repairs myself, is there any advice I should follow, or anything I should avoid doing?
4:  How do I locate and identify the reed switch so that I can remove it?

Comment: No, this is not the right stack (sub-forum) for a laptop repair question.  EE.SE is about electronics design.  The right one would be SuperUser, which is where I will migrate this question.

Answer (score 3):

Before going that route, I would change the settings in your operating system to ignore a closed lid.  In Windows 7, for example, the setting is in the Control Panel > Power Settings:

[image: PowerOptions]

I've taken apart a few laptops, and it's always harder to get them back together than I think it's going to be :)

Good luck!

Comment: I'll try that and see if it works.  I honestly don't know why I didn't think of that, but I'm grateful that you saved me from having to perform surgery.

Comment: @user40146 No problem!  I often miss the easy stuff for the interesting stuff :)